# Limit $\frac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}-\cos(x)}{x^3\sin(x)}$ as $x\to 0$

Tags: limits, indeterminate-forms

We have to find the limit:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^\frac{-x^2}{2}-\cos(x)}{x^3\sin(x)}$$

I was stuck, but was able to find the limit using series expansion as $\dfrac{1}{4}$.

How can we calculate the limit with standard limits like

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{e^x-1}{x}=1\\\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$$

etc.

Also I didn't try L'hospital as that would be too complicated.

Comment: It's not 1/4, the function blows up near 0.

Comment: just look at it, it's 1/0

Comment: Sorry sir I made a typo! Sorry for that, theres a minus sign

Comment: As for your second question, why wouldn't you use L'Hospital's rule? If any, it makes the expression simpler to evaluate

Comment: I don't think the limit is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Anyways I am not good in math so.. I may miss some factors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Taylor polynomials, you have 
$$
\frac {1-\frac {x^2}2+\frac {x^4}{8}+O (x^6)-(1-\frac {x^2}2+\frac {x^4}{24}+O (x^6))}{x^3\sin x}
= \frac {\frac {x^4}{12}+O (x^6)}{x^3\sin x}\to\frac1 {12}.
$$
You cannot expect to use limits as simple as those in your question, because this limit depends on the terms of degree two in the expansion, while the two limits you quote depend on the terms of  degree one.

Comment: What is O?  is it a varaible

Comment: I did this but I quess missed something. Thank you!

Comment: @SakethMalyala: [Big O notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Answer (score 2):

We can proceed as follows
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2} - \cos x}{x^{3}\sin x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2} - 1 + 1 - \cos x}{x^{4}}\cdot\frac{x}{\sin x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{e^{-x^{2}/2} - 1 + 2\sin^{2}(x/2)}{x^{4}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{-2t^{2}} - 1 + 2\sin^{2}t}{16t^{4}}\text{ (putting }x = 2t)\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{-2t^{2}} - 1 + 2t^{2} + 2\sin^{2}t - 2t^{2}}{t^{4}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{16}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{e^{-2t^{2}} - 1 + 2t^{2}}{t^{4}} + \frac{1}{8}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}t - t^{2}}{t^{4}}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^{u} - 1 - u}{u^{2}} + \frac{1}{8}\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t + t}{t}\cdot\frac{\sin t - t}{t^{3}}\text{ (putting }u = -2t^{2})\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{8}\cdot 2\cdot\frac{1}{6}\notag\\
&= \frac{1}{12}\notag
\end{align}
The limits $$\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^{u} - 1 - u}{u^{2}} = \frac{1}{2},\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{\sin t - t}{t^{3}} = -\frac{1}{6}$$ are easily evaluated via Taylor's series or L'Hospital's Rule.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
add 1 and minus 1 from the numerator.
take the exponent along with -1 and the cos function along with +1
now apply basic limit (like the property u have stated above for exponents) and expand $$ 1-cos(x)$$ to get $$2sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$$

U will reach the answer. (Apologies. Newbie at LaTeX)

Comment: I will try to send a picture of this solution too

Comment: Your answer is wrong, since : $ 1 - cos(x) = 2sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$

Comment: My bad @CharalamposFilippatos