# Calculate the Given Limit without using L'Hôpital's and Expansion

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> > If $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^3 \sin x}$$

Exsit then Calculate Above limit **without using  L'Hôpital's and Expansion**.

**My Approach:**

$$l= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^3 \sin x}$$

$$l= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-1)+(1-\cos x)}{x^3 \sin x}$$

$$l= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(e^\frac{-x^2}{2}-1)(\frac{-x^2}{2})}{\frac{-x^2}{2} \cdot (x^4) \cdot(\frac{\sin x}{x})}+\frac{(1-\cos x)(x^2)}{(x^2 ) \cdot \frac{(\sin x)}{x} \cdot x^4}$$

But I am Stuck Here.
Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: [The same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2221910/limit-frace-frac-x22-cosxx3-sinx-as-x-to-0) was asked a couple of years ago. However, I'm not sure if you can completely avoid using Taylor series or L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^3 \sin x} =\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^4} \frac x {\sin x}$$

and

$$\frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-\cos x}{x^4}=\frac14 \frac{e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}-1+\frac {x^2}2}{\frac{x^4}4}+ \frac{1-\frac {x^2}2-\cos x}{x^4}$$

then refer to

- [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/387333/505767)

Comment: In the link they claim solution under "if we know beforehand the limit exists". It means uncomplete solution.

Comment: In the original post it said "if the limit exists".

Comment: Yes you are right, it is a (big) issue with that way to solve it. Here we are assuming it exists.